# Can someone explain unique coprocessor execution behavior we are noticing?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Our Environment :

- We have 44 Region Servers,
- The table has 572 regions,
- Each region server has 13 regions
- Each region has anywhere between 40K to 110K records
- Each Region Server is 32 Core/190GB RAM

My issue is when i run a coprocessor which runs on all these regions then i get radically different execution time on the regions of a single region server.

For e.g. One region took 3.9 seconds whereas another took 8.9 seconds on the same region server with nearly same no. of rows.

Is this normal behavior? Do all the region coprocessor execute under a single JVM or each region has its own Handler in its own JVM?

What is the significance of hbase.regionserver.handler.count ? It is set to 100. Does this mean 100 threads in single JVM or multiple JVMs?

Comment: If you down vote it would be nice to mention the reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answers for some of the questions:

> Is this normal behavior? Do all the region coprocessor execute under a single JVM or each region has its own Handler in its own JVM?

All the regions are handled by a single JVM process.

> What is the significance of hbase.regionserver.handler.count ? It is set to 100. Does this mean 100 threads in single JVM or multiple JVMs?

This is the max no. of threads spun in the HBase JVM process for handling requests to particluar regions.+